# Save Continue Editing

Tags: config

Is it possible to configure "Save & Continue Editing" as default mode? 
I know there is option to select it when adding entry but I want to configure so that always is the case for one of the channel.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's currently not a configuration option, but there is a Control-S (Windows) / Command-S (OSX) shortcut that should work on every page in the Control Panel that basically says "save and stay on the same page".

Comment: Is this still the case? Would love a preference in admin (maybe against the logged-in user) to allow "save and continue" as default.

Answer (score 3):

If you install my [Guano plugin](https://github.com/aelvan/Guano-Craft), it adds an additional "Save & Continue Editing" button above the default buttons. Also, if you have several tabs, it will return to the active one when saving.

It also adds some other GUI changes, like making the sidebar "float", so that you have access to the save buttons even if you scroll down the page.

Hope things like this makes it way into Craft somewhere down the road.